# How to trigger mouseover with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a `mouseover` event on an element on this page: [idealista](https://www.idealista.com/).

If you open DevTools and put your mouse over one of the elements, it will send a `/px/xhr/api/v2/collector` request if your mouse was not in the viewport before. Payload of this request contains Base64 encoded information about the event:

```
[
    {
        "t": "PX297",
        "d": {
            "PX38": "mouseover",
            "PX70": 1631,
            "PX157": "true",
            "PX72": "#home-image",
            "PX34": "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null\n    at kt (https://www.idealista.com/px/client/main.min.js:2:13662)\n    at HTMLBodyElement.Wn (https://www.idealista.com/px/client/main.min.js:2:20855)",
            "PX78": 957,
            "PX79": 321,
            "PX850": 2,
            "PX851": 2392,
            "PX371": true,
            "PX96": "https://www.idealista.com/"
        }
    }
]
```

I can trigger `click` event (by `$('#home-image').click()`). But when I am trying to do that with `mouseover` or `mouseenter`, no result:

```
$('#home-image').click() // Sending request is triggered
$('#home-image').mouseover() // Sending request is NOT triggered
$('#home-image').mouseenter() // Sending request is NOT triggered
```

UPD:

None of these trigger the request:

```
for (let e of ['enter', 'over', 'move', 'leave', 'out']) {
    $('#home-image').trigger('mouse' + e);
}
```

Comment: Try [dispatch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Comment: Take a look at the Event handlers for Javascript.  Without defining custom ones, there are a bunch which would be very handy for you to know. :) . Even i sometimes forget some of them.

Comment: @JonP `.dispatchEvent` worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use a `.dispatchEvent` (thanks @JonP).

```
var x = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
x.initMouseEvent("mouseover", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
document.getElementById('home-image').dispatchEvent(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `mouseenter`

```
$('#home-image').trigger('mouseenter');
```

Comment: I think he has asked for javascript specifically.
`var home_image = document.getElementById('home-image');
home_image .addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) { do  stuff here })`

Comment: ...But he's using jquery explicitely, and jquery is javascript in the first place.

Comment: Does it trigger sending request with info about an event?

Comment: Also can be done with `$('#home-image').mouseenter()` (no parameters is intentional)

Comment: @stasdeep , it will trigger the mouse enter event. The sending request is irrelevant. If the sending request is part of a mouse enter event handler for that element, it should be triggered.

Comment: @JonP no, this request is relevant, because it's a sign that I was able to trigger it correctly. I don't know what listeners are set there, but `.trigger('mousenter')` (or `mouseover`) are definitely not working.

Comment: @stasdeep " I don't know what listeners are set" - well that's the problem, we don't know what listeners to trigger. It's the listeners that are important, not the code within. Try `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript solution:

```js
document.getElementById('home-image')
  .addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    // apply actions here
  });
```

JQuery solution:

```js
$('#home-image').mouseenter(() => {
  // apply actions here
});
```

Comment: Does it trigger sending the request?

Comment: You have to implement that yourself :)

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand what I need. I want to trigger it on a third-party page (link is in the answer). The problem is that `.mouseover` and `.mouseenter` triggers are not working with the listener set on the page.